# 500 Error when GET request to /auth/twitter for Oauth Twitter on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, twitter, oauth

I have gotten the twitter oauth to work locally but after deploying to Heroku, the GET request to /auth/twitter is returning a 500 error.

```
 # _redeem_tweet.erb

<h1>Twitter Redeem</h1>
<%= link_to image_tag('sign-in-with-twitter.png'), "/auth/twitter?id=#{ params[:id] }&ref=#{ params['ref'] }" %>

# routes.rb
get 'auth/twitter/callback' => 'api/v1/skoshinvites#twitter_auth'



   # omniauth.rb
    Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  if ENV['TWITTER_CUSTOMER_KEY'].blank? || ENV['TWITTER_CUSTOMER_SECRET'].blank?
    warn '*' * 80
    warn 'WARNING: Missing consumer key or secret. First, register an app with Twitter at'
    warn 'https://dev.twitter.com/apps to obtain OAuth credentials. Then, start the server'
    warn 'with the command: CONSUMER_KEY=abc CONSUMER_SECRET=123 rails server'
    warn '*' * 80
  else
    provider :twitter, ENV['TWITTER_CUSTOMER_KEY'], ENV['TWITTER_CUSTOMER_SECRET']
  end
end
```

I get the following from the Heroku logs:

> 2015-12-23T03:06:49.727838+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/auth/twitter?id=11&ref=KKYVL" host=skoshapp.herokuapp.com request_id=a2b359b8-3ff3-45cc-a39c-393e2775b840 fwd="184.153.18.149" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=90ms status=500 bytes=1669

Comment: Have you set the TWITTER_CUSTOMER_KEY and TWITTER_CUSTOMER_SECRET environment variables on Heroku?

Comment: I had the TWITTER_CUSTOMER_KEY and TWITTER_CUSTOMER_SECRET environment variables (config vars) set, but they needed to be hard-coded as the config vars are loaded after the initializers.

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved by removing the conditional in omniauth.rb and just providing the provider. I also had to hard code the customer_key and customer_secret_key. Apparently, the config vars from Heroku weren't being applied before the app initializers (i.e. omniauth.rb).

Answer (score 0):

I had solved this problem by correctly specifying the **Callback URI / Redirect URL and website URL** on path MyApp > User authentication settings > edit

[image]